# Currently not change css style in WordPress site

Tags: css, wordpress, ftp

I want to change some design layout of a WordPress site. So first change css code from edit option but then currently didn't show change of any layout but later that change automatically. Now I want to some change by FTP but now the same process back again. How can I solve it ?

Comment: you change your css in ftp than after refresh to CTRL+F5  and check

Answer (score 2):

I think I understand the question. It sounds like it is just cached. 
U can use CTRL+F5 to refresh cache, rather than just refreshing your browser normally.
Otherwise here is a wordpress blog about clearing your cache
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-clear-cache-1